# Change only one view on state change in ui.router?

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router, ngroute, angularjs-view

I have a simple layout like so:

```
__________________  ________
|                |  | Side |
|  Main section  |  | -bar |
|________________|  |______|
```

The "Main section" exposes forms to the user; based on their selection that "Main section" `state` should change (i.e.: a different partial should be loaded). How do I facilitate this with `UI.router`?

E.g.: change only `columnOne` in the `/about` state: http://plnkr.co/edit/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the state changes, all the new state's views and those of any ancestor state will be loaded. So if you want view A to remain unchanged while view B changes to view C, then view A's state will have to be an ancestor of views B and C. So you need an intermediary (possibly abstract) state.

[Here is a Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cIbOSUrSrARKSiOF6R7)

Comment: So basically you're saying that the only solution is to replicate the layout code in each state? - I.e.: `<div ui-view="newcontent0"></div><div ui-view="sidebar"></div>`, `<div ui-view="newcontent1"></div><div ui-view="sidebar"></div>` &etc.?

Comment: Ok, I see what you're getting at now. You need to use a named view in a parent state. Will update.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was after.

Comment: @AT - I've added a Plunker. Hope this helps. Please excuse the styling.

Comment: Hi @david004. I slightly edited your version, but can't seem to get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/a3YCM

Comment: Fork from my Plunker and make your changes incrementally until it breaks, then let me know which change broke it. I will then try and tell you why. Use Plunker.

Comment: I have isolated the problem: it's from facilitating multiple named views. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24265610