# Scope inheritance fails with multiple-named views?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

It breaks when moving from ([Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RJapIWXCYVG4lvpveUfy?p=preview)):

```
.state('home', {url: '/home', template: '<pre>{{parentProp}}</pre>',
                controller: function ($scope) {$scope.parentProp = ['home'];}})
```

To ([Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/giW3XRspEV7SEPM1UDeC?p=preview)):

```
.state('home', {url: '/home', views: {'': {template: '<pre>{{parentProp}}</pre>'}},
                controller: function ($scope) {$scope.parentProp = ['home'];}})`
```

Specifically I have a `'sidebar'` state I want to add as a secondary state to `'home'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view needs its own controller:

```
.state('home', {url: '/home',
                views: {'': {template: '<pre>{{parentProp}}</pre>',
                             controller: function ($scope) {
                                             $scope.parentProp = ['home'];
                                         }
                             }
                        },
                })`
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/giW3XRspEV7SEPM1UDeC?p=preview